# what's wrong with my java program?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumOne {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ley = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean num2;
    int num;

    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    num = ley.nextInt();

}
public boolean isPositive(boolean num) {
    if (a > 0) {
        System.out.print("positive");
    } else {
        System.out.print("negatinve");
    }
    return num;
}
```

C:\Users\nimzkie\Desktop\NumOne.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable a
location: class NumOne
        if(a>0){
           ^
1 error

Process completed.

Comment: Whats wrong? `cannot find symbol symbol : variable a` . have you ever declare variable `a`?

Comment: same error.. i changed it to num..

Answer (score 5):

The error message is very specific: You are using `a` in your `if` statement, but Java has no idea what `a` is. You probably meant to say `if(num > 0)`. And you don't mean `boolean num`, you mean `int num`.

Comment: can u pls paste the final program ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons for that error: http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm

You did not declare variable a.

`int a = 0;`